# How to get selected radio button in group using MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have one Window and I want to change one part of this window from another part who have few RadioButton. And from this radio button I want client choose who section is need to see in the another part of window. Like Options window in Visual Studio.

I have few radio buttons in one group and want the view model to know which radio button is selected when the user selects one of them.

I found an [example how I can bind in XAML](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/720497/Binding-Radio-Buttons-to-a-Single-Property) but can't understand how the view model can know which radio button is selected.

Here is my simple view:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Settings" IsChecked="{Binding SelectSettingSection}" Content="Language" />
<RadioButton GroupName="Settings" IsChecked="{Binding SelectSettingSection}" Content="Color" />
<RadioButton GroupName="Settings" IsChecked="{Binding SelectSettingSection}" Content="Description" />
<RadioButton GroupName="Settings" IsChecked="{Binding SelectSettingSection}" Content="Theme" />
<RadioButton GroupName="Settings" IsChecked="{Binding SelectSettingSection}" Content="Database" />
```

Is possible to have only one property for this group of radio buttons, or do I need to have five properties for every radio button on view model?

"SelectSectionSetting" is to know who part is choose, I know is checked but who exactly I couldn't know

Comment: Your codeproject link is the best solution, spend some time to understand it.

Comment: include property definition for `SelectSettingSection`

Comment: You should add a ViewModel. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420911/get-selected-radio-button-in-a-group-wpf

Comment: Why do you need RadioButton for this behavior? If you want something like Options in VS maybe TreeView or ListBox is better choice.

Comment: Also this article could be useful and give some ideas: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/12/lets-code-data-binding-to-radio-button.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me help you understand the codeproject link you posted, as Novitchi S said is the one that will point you to the right solution.

What it really does the trick is the converter, which takes two values 1. the selected object (bounded in your radio button) 2. the associated object with the radio button (passed as converter parameter). What converter does, is to check if the associated with the radio button object is the same (equals) as the selected object. Then it converts this value to true or false and passes it to the radio button